# unable to turn room light on all the time

Tags: electrical-panel

My house was owned and build by an electrician so the had a main panel connected to a relay box (picture attached) before goes out to the light switches (picture attached). The problem now is that I'm not able to turn on the ceiling light in one of the bedroom.  Sometime I can turn it on but for a few times before it won't turn on again. What do you think the problem is? the switch goes bad or the relay box goes bad? Another thing, what goes bad if the light stay on all the time? Finally, where can I find replacement parts for both relays panel and the light switches.  Thank you.

[image: main panel and relays]

[image: light switches]

Comment: The switches are in the [P&S/legrand product line](http://www.legrand.us/categories/electricalwiringdevices/electrical-accessories/low-voltage-switching-components.aspx).   The relays are possibly GE and similar to the RR7 which is commonly available. Your relays appear to have leads, the RR7 has terminals.  The RR7 may or may not work as a replacement.

Comment: I showed the picture to my dad to see if he could identify the relays.  He said they might be GE and if they are the GE RR7 would be the current replacement since the switches don't have indicator lights.  Can you provide any markings on the relays?

Comment: If your question was in the US, the first thing I would suspect was a failing switch, and the second would be a bulb not quite fully screwed in....

Comment: Tried to add pictures but do not know how! The inscription is: 1/2HP 125VAC Tungsten Ballast  Bryant.

Answer (score 2):

Bryant Low voltage relays are no longer made.  However the GE RR7 is a direct replacement. Google "GE RR7" or talk to an electrical supply house in your area.

Same thing, for the switches.  You probably have Bryant branded low voltage switches (since the relays were Bryant). You can purchase the [P&S/Legrand](http://www.legrand.us/categories/electricalwiringdevices/electrical-accessories/low-voltage-switching-components.aspx) brand for replacements.  Again google to purchase or contact and Electrical Supply house in your area, like the relays these will not be in carried at a big box store.

In your case, the component that likely has gone bad is the relay.  When you push the switch can you hear the relay click even when the light doesn't come on? If so, the switch is working correctly but the relay is not making contact.  On the other hand if there is no noise from the relay then it's likely the switch.  Since your problem is intermittent its not likely there is a wiring issue either on low or line voltage side, it's most likely that the relay contacts just aren't good anymore.